# Buildship doesn't import dependency declared by plugin

Tags: gradle, gatling, buildship, gatling-plugin

After I import the project (**Import -> Existing Gradle Project**) or refresh the project (**Gradle -> Refresh Gradle Project**) the list of dependencies shown in **Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Project and External Dependencies** does not contain the **scala-library** dependency declared by the Gatling Gradle plugin. If I run the "dependencies" task on the project, the scala-library dependency is listed as the last element under "compileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'main'".

Some context:

The project is using Gradle wrapper version 6.8 .
The project is a subproject.
The project applies the Gatling Gradle plugin like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'io.gatling.gradle' version '3.6.1'
}
```

The library that should be on the build path is this one:

```
\--- org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.13.6
```

I'm using Spring Tool Suite version 4.18.0.RELEASE based on Eclipse 2023-03

I tried declaring the dependency explicitly in the project.
I tried applying the 'scala' plugin to the project.
Both didn't work (I refreshed the Gradle Project after both attempts).

I tried looking at the source code of the Gatling Gradle Plugin, it seems to be declaring the library as "implementation" at line 94 (https://github.com/gatling/gatling-gradle-plugin/blob/v3.6.1/src/main/groovy/io/gatling/gradle/GatlingPlugin.groovy).

Is my configuration wrong or is there an incompatibility that I'm not aware of?

Comment: " id 'io.gatling.gradle' version '3.6.1'" First thing first, this is an old version, please upgrade to 3.9.2.2.

Comment: I upgraded the version to '3.9.2.2'. Refreshing the Gradle Project fails with the following error: FAILURE: Build Failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Failed to notify dependency resolution listener. > Could not find netty-resolver-dsn-native-macos-4.1.65.Final-osx-aarch_64.jar (io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-native-macos:4.1.65.Final). Searched in the following locations: <repo_baseurl>io/netty/netty-resolver-dns-native-macos/4.1.65.Final/netty-resolver-dns-native-macos-4.1.65.Final-osx-aarch_64.jar . Why is it looking for a native MacOS jar and why is it not present on Maven central?